# how to create integration key on production mode in docusign

Tags: docusignapi

My client has given me a paid account of Docusign. So how to create an integrator key on the production account?
       I lot of search on google and they are suggestions me that go to admin->API & Keys and will show **Add  Integration Keys** button, but I'm not able to see this kind of button. Does anyone guide me on how to create an integrator key on the production or paid account into Docusign?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. PLEASE check (accept) the best answer to your questions. THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

To create a production integration key on DocuSign:

1. Open a [free developer account](https://developers.docusign.com/)
2. Use the admin tool within the developer sandbox to create an integration key
3. Build/test your application
4. Pass the [go-live procedure](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/go-live)
5. You now have an integration key on the production platforms. And you have a second integration key in the developer sandbox. The developer sandbox key can and should be used for on-going testing and development

Comment: Thanks, Larry for letting me, but my client already created a paid account. Is there any way to convert this production account to a development account with any trouble? Or If I'll create a new demo account and can use the **integration key** to my client account. If yes how? Or any other best way?

Comment: Use the procedure in the answer. You'll use the paid account as part of step 4

Comment: Larry, Could you please explain, how to use the paid account into the developer sandbox account?  Because I'm not able to login to my client paid account as a sandbox account. Please give me any suggestions on it.

Comment: Your first step is to create a free developer account. You only need the paid account in step 4. Until you get to step 4, forget about the paid account. It doesn't matter until step 4.

Comment: But Larry my client already purchase a paid account. So what should I do now?

Comment: Again, it doesn't matter that an account has already been paid for. A paid account is not needed until you get to step 4. At that point, the paid account is needed. Before step 4 if you have a paid account or not, it does not matter.